# how to integrate paypal with return data?

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have created a new business account in paypal and created a button but I have these two problems;
1. when I passed the price for service, and user click (pay now) button then user go to paypal page but the price that I put is not showing as a primary price in paypal page. 
the item price is empty in paypal. user has to put the price in paypal too.
and the price that has passed is in (Options: service price: 12) which is not counted in the total amount.

this is the code of the button that I insert it in my page:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="3YNEZFSSJNVR4">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="service price">service price</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

1. the second problem how I can pass the transaction info to my website to record it in my database? is that need special account different than standard (free) account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's look like you not have pass the amount value to paypal

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
```

Comment: the price that I passed will show as an option and not counted in the total amount